# Finding my app, compiled executable code

Tags: ios, xcode

Once the program is built, where on the hard drive is it?

Does Xcode help one set up where the finished product should reside at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to take a look at ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData. Note that under Lion the ~/Library directory is hidden by default, you can get to it through the terminal.

A super simple way to get there is via Xcode. Simply open up the Organizer, either Window -> Organizer or Cmd-Shift-2, click on Projects. From there you can easily delete the Derived data, which is the most common case. Clicking on the little arrow button will open it in the finder.

Comment: Cool; Is is possible to change the default location where app is built?

Comment: Yes, open preferences, go to Locations. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

Usually it's in *Derived Data* folder that you can get path to in Xcode's organizer (Cmd + Shift + 2). Check the "Projects" tab. You'll see the project list on the left. Select a project in question and go straight to it's Derived Data folder. Check the folders for appropriate build configurations (Debug/Release) for application bundles.

Answer (score -1):

The other answers give you the default folder - if it's not there there is another way.

You can find it by right clicking on the .app file in the Products folder and choosing 'Reveal in Finder'.

Comment: Tried this :) It brings me back to source, not to the compiled version for some reason

Comment: He already indicated that he didn't know how to change the default.

Comment: Ah, I often work on projects inherrited from other developers - the default is rarely where the app ends up :) Should have mentioned this in my answer!